# C/C++ error: expected initializer before defined function

Tags: c++, c, solaris, initializer

I am porting Einstein@Home (Radio Pulsar Edition) to Solaris and am stuck on `erp_execinfo_plus.c` that reports the error below.

```
builder@bertha:~/brp/src$ g++ -g -I/export/home/builder/brp/install/include/libxml2 -I/export/home/builder/brp/install/include/boinc -I/usr/gnu/include -I/export/home/builder/brp/install/include -DHAVE_INLINE -DBOINCIFIED -DUSE_CPU_RESAMP -DUSE_FFTW_FFT -DNDEBUG -DLOGLEVEL=info -ggdb3 -rdynamic -O3 -Wall -fprofile-use -c /export/home/builder/brp/src/erp_extract.c 
/export/home/builder/brp/src/erp_extract.c:8:12: error: expected initializer before 'VPARAMS'
 void fatal VPARAMS ((const char *format, ...)) {
            ^~~~~~~
/export/home/builder/brp/src/erp_extract.c:16:16: error: expected initializer before 'VPARAMS'
 void non_fatal VPARAMS ((const char *format, ...)) {
                ^~~~~~~
```

I have tried numerous iterations to correct the issue by moving code blocks around, redefining them as a struct and overloading. I have even used gcc and the gcc/g++ preprocessor outputs to find the error to no avail.

gcc:

> `/export/home/builder/brp/src/erp_extract.c:16:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'VPARAMS'`

**NOTES:**

1. The `erp_extract.c` file is the minimum source code to reproduce the error.
2. The `#include` is the default **binutils** `sysdef.h`

**erp_extract.c**

```
#include "sysdep.h"

static FILE *ostream; /* output stream */

void fatal(const char *, ...) ATTRIBUTE_PRINTF_1 ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN;
void non_fatal(const char *, ...) ATTRIBUTE_PRINTF_1;
void report(const char *, va_list) ATTRIBUTE_PRINTF(1,0);

void fatal VPARAMS ((const char *format, ...)) {
    VA_OPEN (args, format);
    VA_FIXEDARG (args, const char *, format);

    report(format, args);
    VA_CLOSE (args);
}

void non_fatal VPARAMS ((const char *format, ...)) {
    VA_OPEN (args, format);
    VA_FIXEDARG (args, const char *, format);

    report(format, args);
    VA_CLOSE (args);
}

void report(const char * format, va_list args)
{
    vfprintf(ostream, format, args);
    putc ('\n', ostream);
}
```

Comment: if `VPARAMS` a macro?

Comment: In the original code there would be a definition of `VPARAMS` somewhere, look it up

Comment: [Apparently](https://github.com/LLNL/PnMPI/issues/4) VPARAMS was removed from gcc's ansidecl.h a long time ago: https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2014-01/msg00727.html

Comment: It would appear that @DavidWohlferd is correct. It was removed in binutils-2.12.

Comment: I not aware of any need to explicitly mark functions that have variable numbers of parameters anymore (in fact, I wasn't aware that it *used* to be a requirement).  gcc has no [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for this currently.  I'd be tempted to either remove references to VPARAMS, or #define it away (along with lots of comments about why).